# Creating summary table by dividing values by the average of the observations in the surrounding area in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

The minimal sample of my data is;

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

tbl <- data.table(store = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'),
                  year = c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018),
                  week = c(12,13,15,16,2,3,4,18,19,20,22,24,25,1,2,3,2),
                  insert = sample(0:1,size = 17,replace = T),
                  demand = sample(200:250,size = 17,replace=T))
```

I'd like to create a summary table which is calculated in this way;

to calculate the effect where the insert column is 1, I must divide the demand value of the insert column by the average of the demand value of the nearest weeks within a year, **which takes the value of the insert column zero around that week**

For example, if I need to calculate for store A at 2017 and 3rd week, it must be:

```
rate <- 209 / mean(c(206,245))
```

but if the year has more than one inserts, like for store B at year 2017 it should be means of the rates (for week 19 and 20):

```
rate <- mean(224 / mean(c(240,236)), 245 / mean(c(240,236)))
```

and if I can't find two values around it, I have to calculate a ratio by dividing it by the only value I find. for example store C at year 2017:

```
rate <- 243 / 224
```

if I can find no value around the inserted row, I need to pass 1.

finally the summary table should look like;

```
desired_tbl <- data.table(store = c('A','A','B','C','C'),
                          year = c(2017,2018,2017,2017,2018),
                          rate = c(0.927,0.97,0.941,1.08,1))

desired_tbl

  store  year  rate
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      2017 0.927
2 A      2018 0.97 
3 B      2017 0.941
4 C      2017 1.08 
5 C      2018 1
```

I can do all of them by writing for loops and tons of conditions but I'm looking for a vectorised way to accomplish. dplyr solutions are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you have an error in your calculation of 2017-B.  Should be `mean(c(224/238, 245/238))`, which equals 0.985.. You accidentally have `mean(224/228, 245/238)`, which is effectively setting the `trim` parameter of the `mean()` function to 1.029412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `demand` values having `insert` values of 1 with NA giving `d` and then fill in `d` forwards and backwards by group taking the mean of the two directions and dividing into `demand` giving `rate`.  Then keep only the `insert` 1 rows and aggregate `rate` by `store`/`year` group using `mean` on what is left.  If any `rate` is not finite use 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

tbl %>%
  mutate(d = ifelse(insert == 1, NA, demand)) %>%
  group_by(store, year) %>%
  mutate(rate = demand / 
    rowMeans(cbind(na.locf0(d), na.locf0(d, fromLast = TRUE)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(insert == 1) %>%
  summarize(rate = mean(rate, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(rate = ifelse(is.finite(rate), rate, 1))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  store  year  rate
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      2017 0.927
2 A      2018 0.973
3 B      2017 0.985
4 C      2017 1.08 
5 C      2018 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way

- First, identify the store-years, where the `insert=1` rows are consecutive, and collapse them (i.e, take the average of those). In your example, there is only one like this (2017-B, weeks 19/20). Take these collapsed rows, and bind them back to the `insert=0` rows, ordering back to `store`, `year`,`week`

```
tbl[, `:=`(demand=as.double(demand), insert_id=rleid(insert))]
tbl <- rbind(
  tbl[insert==0],
  tbl[insert==1][, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=T), by=.(store,year,insert_id)]
)[order(store,year,week)]
```

- Next, get the values before and after the `insert=1` rows, generate the mean (`m`) of those values by row, estimate the ratio of `demand` to `m`, and retain the `insert=1` rows.

```
tbl[, c("v1","v2"):=shift(demand,c(-1,1)), by=.(store, year)]
tbl[, m:=mean(c(v1,v2), na.rm=T), by=1:nrow(tbl)]
tbl[, rate:=demand/m][insert==1,.(rate=mean(fifelse(is.na(rate),1,rate))), by=.(store,year)]
```

Output:

```
    store  year      rate
   <char> <num>     <num>
1:      A  2017 0.9268293
2:      A  2018 0.9727273
3:      B  2017 0.9852941
4:      C  2017 1.0848214
5:      C  2018 1.0000000
```

Its not identical as your desired output, because I believe you have miscalculated 2017-B.